# Fontconfig: How to add local customization file

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I need to add some local font directories. one option is to edit fonts.conf and add dir tag to add directories. But it is not good to edit this file, for local customization local.conf is used but when I installed fontconfig local.conf is not created. Can anyone help me to find correct settings to build fontconfig so that it creates local.conf, or how can I include local.conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this, Basically we have to create a local.conf and add customized configurations to it. 
It should be read automatically by font-config, But it is not the case then check that if conf.d have some file which will include local.conf (by default that files is 51-local.conf).